# Can't get the oven light cover off

Tags: oven

I have a Fisher n Paykel OB60SVMX2 oven that I cannot figure out.
The manual implies you screw out the cover and pull the bulb out.

The problem is the top heating element does not have enough clearance to remove the bulb cover.  It hits the top element as it comes out.  Tilting the heating element down doesn't help in any way.

Am I supposed to remove an oven element?  Such a bad design to have to remove the element to replace the bulb!  It feels wrong.  So I'm asking for some wisdom and help here.  Any help/hints appreciated

Picture now attached.  Light is on the right top rear of the oven.  The heating element is angled down as far as it goes.  When the element is up all the way it still gets in the way of the light cover coming off.

There are two screws that appear to hold something but not clear if that is the element.  The two what look like inner screws are more like rivets.  It's not clear how that comes out.  I'd not be pleased if I have to remove the entire oven to get this out.

[image]

Comment: how about a picture of the inside.

Comment: If the oven element would just unplug like the surface elements do, then I would say to do so, but I think most oven elements do not unplug from inside the oven. They are usually held in by screws and then must be pulled out to release them. I am not sure if removing the oven element can be done without pulling the oven out from the wall and accessing the back. In our oven the upper element does not interfere with removing the cover over the lamp. Could it be that in your oven someone replaced the original element with a wider one?

Comment: You say element (like heating element) then bulb , they are different, an element usually has a small flange that is held in place by a screw. Lamps usually screw in so what are we talking about?

Comment: @Ed Beal I took the OP's statement to mean that the upper heating element is interfering with the removal of the glass cover of the bulb.

Comment: This design was clearly inspired by "the appliance repair-persons Stay Employed Initiative" or else "The Dark Oven Society." I'll have to remember to check before I buy my next oven, and not buy one like this.

Comment: I agree with you there @Ecnerwal .   It's all original. The new models don't put the lights in silly places like this.  They are front top centre.

Answer (score 1):

The two Phillip screws you clearly see hold the thermocouple for the temperature gauge. The two that look like rivets are probably screws that need to be removed with a socket or nut driver. Turn off the breaker for the oven. Verify oven's off by turning it on... the light's out so you can't use that. Remove those two screws with a socket or nut driver and pull out the element just enough to give you clearance to remove the light cover. Be careful not to pull out the element far enough to disconnect it from the wires behind it. Once the bulb is replaced, put the element back in place. good luck.